# sync folder /home/vagrant with project root?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

This is my setting in my vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/test/kata"
```

If I start my VM and login with `vagrant ssh` I am in the empty folder `/home/vagrant`. If I want to go to folder kata, I have to cd to it like this:

```
cd ../test/kata
```

How can I tell vagrant to show all files from `/home/test/kata` at `/home/vagrant`?

I also tried

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/vagrant", "/home/test/kata"
```

But this just returns an error:

> - The host path of the shared folder is missing: /home/vagrant

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch them (got confused with host/guest in the [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html)):

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/test/kata", "/home/vagrant/kata"
```

Also I could not map everything to `/home/vagrant`, because then I can't login into the VM, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271150/vagrant-permission-denied-publickey